# Difficulties creating an automatic file moving script (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, automation, backup

I'll start by stating that i'm pretty new to Powershell but from what i hear it can be pretty powerful.

with that said i'll specify the problem.

i'm trying to write a Powershell script destined to run daily and check the total size of a number of specific folders, inside of each of these folders there are folders sorted by, let's say names.
what i'm aiming for as the final result is a script that checks these folder's size and if it exceeds of the defined limit i set beforehand, their content will be moved to a pre-defined destination.
The files will be moved to a folder with the same name as they were located in before.

here is where I've gotten so far:

```
$Folder_A = "C:\Users\location_A"
$Folder_B = "C:\Users\location_B"
$Folder_C = "C:\Users\location_C"
if((get-childitem $Folder_A , $Folder_B , $Folder_C | where {$_.name -eq name_1-or $_.name -eq $Name_2} | measure-object -property length -sum).sum -gt 30000) {write-host "success"}
```

OUTPUT?

```
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-eq' operator.
At line:1 char:63
+ if((get-childitem $input , $Temp , $Tiffs | where {$_.name -eq <<<<  I001 -or $_.name -eq I002} | measure-object -property length -sum).sum -gt 30000) {
write-host "success"}
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression
```

if anyone is able to help progress with this thing i would appriciate it alot!

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a space in where closure. It should be:

```
where {$_.name -eq name_1 -or $_.name -eq $Name_2}
```

To be sure that is working corectly use () so your statement will be:

```
 where {($_.name -eq name_1) -or ($_.name -eq $Name_2)}
```

**UPDATE**
My full (tested) script to calculate sum of selected directories:

```
$names = @("IIS", "IIS Express")
$folders = @("C:\Program Files", "C:\Program Files (x86)")
$x = (gci $folders | where {$names -contains $_.name})
$sum = (($x | %{(Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)}) | Measure-Object -Property 'Sum' -Sum).sum
if($sum -gt 3000){write-host "success"}
```

In your case: `$folders = @("C:\Program Files", "C:\Program Files (x86)")` replace with `$folders = @("C:\Users\location_A", "C:\Users\location_B", "C:\Users\location_C")` and in names put what you need

Comment: yeah that was just a typo when i copied the script to the forum but thanks. what else? how do you guys think i should continue this?

Comment: `name_1` should probably be `$name_1`. And the parentheses are not required, since logical operators have lower precedence than comparison operators.

Comment: Hey Garath, I thank you for the quick answer and wonderful solution. i can now continue with the next step of the script, and that will be moving the files to a folder with the same name as the folder they were in. i'm trying to find it on my own but if anyone has an idea on how to even begin, my appreciation will be even greater! :) thanks everyone.

Comment: On stackoverflow mark response as answer, you do not have to thanks

Answer (score 0):

The canonical approach for checking whether a property matches any of a number of references is to put the reference strings into an array and check if the array contains the property value. The names of the folders you want to check should also go into an array rather than single variables.

Try something like this:

```
$src = @(
  "C:\Users\location_A",
  "C:\Users\location_B",
  "C:\Users\location_C"
)

$ref = @(
  "name_1",
  "name_2",
  ...
)

$found = [bool](Get-ChildItem $src `
  | ? { $ref -contains $_.Name } `
  | Measure-Object -property Length -sum `
  | ? { $_.sum -gt 30000 })

if ($found) { write-host "success" }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of directories for the path. 
 If you use -Recurse (even though there aren't any subdirectories to recurse), you can specify the list of filenames as an array argument to the -Include parameter:

```
$Folders = 'C:\Users\location_A','C:\Users\location_B','C:\Users\location_C'
$Files = 'name_1','name_2'

if ((((get-childitem $Folders -Recurse -Include $files | select -ExpandProperty length) | measure -sum).sum) -gt 30000)
  {write-host 'Success'}
```